# MIn max group wise and filter without join in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am trying to find (max+min)/2 for each group. The following is my schema

```
UrlXpathsCount: {url: chararray,leafpathstr: chararray,urlpath_count: long}
```

and I am trying to group it by url field

```
byUrl = GROUP UrlXpathsCount by url;
```

And i am trying to find (max+min)/2 by the following way.

```
midRangeByUrl = FOREACH byUrl{
    urls_desc = order UrlXpathsCount by urlpath_count desc;
    urls_max = limit urls_desc 1;
    urls_asc = order UrlXpathsCount by urlpath_count asc;
    urls_min = limit urls_asc 1;

    GENERATE FLATTEN(urls_max),FLATTEN(urls_min);
};
```

The following is the schema for midRangeByUrl

```
midRangeByUrl: {urls_max::url: chararray,urls_max::leafpathstr: chararray,urls_max::urlpath_count: long,urls_min::url: chararray,urls_min::leafpathstr: chararray,urls_min::urlpath_count: long}
```

The problem i am facing now is that adding a FLATTEN(group) ,FLATTEN(urls_max) , FLATTEN(urls_min) gives me a lot of combinations that I don't want.

I would like to get max + min/2 for each group.

To do this, I am projecting the urlpath_count of both max and min by the following

```
computeMidRange = FOREACH midRangeByUrl generate urls_max::url as mid_url,((DOUBLE)urls_max::urlpath_count+(DOUBLE) urls_min::urlpath_count)/2 as midRange;
```

And I am joining the two tables by the following

```
/* Join computeMidRange  and UrlXpathsCount */
midRangeJoin = join UrlXpathsCount by url , computeMidRange by mid_url using 'replicated';
midRangeOut = FOREACH midRangeJoin GENERATE UrlXpathsCount::url as url,UrlXpathsCount::leafpathstr as leafpathstr,
    UrlXpathsCount::urlpath_count as urlpath_count,computeMidRange::midRange as midRange;
```

and then filter applying the filter

```
templates = FILTER midRangeOut by urlpath_count > midRange;
```

I would like to avoid the midRangeJoin . By somehow computing the midRangeByUrl and projecting the following fields url, urlpath_count ,leafpathstr , (min+max)/2 without the join.

Please help me in figuring this out.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use instead the builtin `MAX` and `MIN` UDFs:

```
UrlXpathsCount = load 'your_data' using PigStorage(',') as (url: chararray,leafpathstr: chararray,urlpath_count: long);
B = GROUP UrlXpathsCount by url;
C = foreach B generate group as url, MAX(UrlXpathsCount.urlpath_count) as max_count, 
                                     MIN(UrlXpathsCount.urlpath_count) as min_count;
D = foreach C generate url, ((double)max_count + (double)min_count)/2 as val;
```

This will do exactly what you want, without nested foreachs or joins. I divided the calculation into `C` and `D` to avoid an extremely long line, but you could do it in one only line too. Just remember to cast the values to `double`, because your `urlpath_count` is a `long` so you won't get any decimals if you don't cast it.